# ParseQuery not taking into consideration Where clause WindowsPhone

Tags: parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I made a new query to select from Article Class with where clause for each item selected. However, it keeps getting the whole list every time although there are selected fields! 
Here is my code:

```
ParseQuery<Article> query = new ParseQuery<Article>();

        if (souCategorie.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            query.WhereEqualTo("idSCategorie", listeSouCategorie.ElementAt(souCategorie.SelectedIndex));
        }
        if(motcle.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            query.WhereContains("nom", motcle.Text);
           // query.WhereContains("description", motcle.Text);
        }
        if(distance.Text.Length>0)
        if (Convert.ToDouble(distance.Text) > 0)
        {
                Debug.WriteLine(distance.Text);
                ParseGeoPoint geo = new ParseGeoPoint();
            geo.Latitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude;
            geo.Longitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude;
            query.WhereWithinDistance("coordonnees", geo, ParseGeoDistance.FromKilometers(Convert.ToDouble(distance.Text)));
        }

        IEnumerable<Article> lst = await query.FindAsync();
        rechercheResult.DataContext = lst.ToList();
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know that queries can do funky stuff when you start trying to use GeoPoint stuff. I would try setting up two queries, one that just queries for objects within a distance, then pass that query into the second query that has the `whereEqualTo` and `whereContains` calls.

Comment: The query keeps selecting all the data even if I don't select the geopoint. and just set the "nom" field.

Comment: Add breakpoints inside each of those if statements. I bet none of them are hitting, then.

Comment: I tried that and it's getting them. I even replaced the whole code with simple where and it's still getting the whole data -_-